# an error occurred while processing this directive in justhost

Tags: mysql, cpanel

when i upload my website to my hosting `Justhost` it not working and it show only error like this

```
an error occurred while processing this directive
```

Please help me to correct this error

Comment: This is caused by incorrect MIME type. If you have added MIME from .htaccess comment them. If it does not ork, you will have to contact yo ur host.

Answer (score 0):

```
try the steps that follow:
```

- Go to cPanel
- Open File Manager from Files section
- Navigate to domain folder
- Check "Perms" column on far right hand side
- Files should be set to: 0644 (this is the UNIX file permissions)
- Folders should be set to: 0755

This will change your file permissions to their proper settings for the justhost file system. Additionally, if you have PHP code within.htm or .html files, you will need to add an additional Apache handler to tell justhost to parse these files as PHP. Do this using Apache Handlers in cPanel: